# Big O Notation in PAC Learning

Tags: machine-learning, big-o, complexity-theory, theory

This may be a very basic question, but I'm currently going through [Andrew Ng's CS229 notes on Learning Theory](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes4.pdf) (specifically PAC Learning). What I see is that the error on a given hypothesis is less than or equal to the error on the best possible hypothesis + an expression inside Big O Notation:

[image: E(h-hat)<=E(h*)+O(sqrt((d/m)log(m/d)+(1/m)log(1/delta))]

From my understanding, Big O notation has to do with convergence of some function. How do I interpret this Big O notation? As someone without a heavy math background, I don't know if I should allow all the vars d, m, and delta to approach infinity, or just plug in values there and ignore the O

Answer (score 3):

You need a bit more information here to answer the question, but looking at the notes we have:

- `h^`: a *specific* hypothesis drawn from domain H
- `h*`: the *best* hypothesis in domain H
- `d`: the number of parameters used to define `h^` and `h*`
- `m`: the number of samples used to learn `h^`
- `delta`: the bound on probability that our inequality holds

Basically what the equation says is that with probability `1 - delta`, you can guarantee that prediction error of a hypothesis drawn from a given domain of hypotheses is bounded uniformly by the prediction error of the *best* hypotheses in this domain as `m` grows.

The interesting thing about this is that it allows you to plan your data collection around what kind of *generalization error guarantees* you want to achieve. So if you wanted to know the bounds on your error to within 99% probability for an algorithm that is parameterized by 10 parameters dependent on how many data samples you have, you would set `delta = 0.01`, `d = 10`, and then calculate the part in the `O(...)` as you increase `m` from 1 to however many data samples you think is reasonable. Plotting that as you vary `m` is one way of determining how many data samples *is* reasonable, and planning your data collection accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to @Engineero post. Here is a generic interpretation of the Big-O notation.

The inequality `a < b + O(f(d,m,delta)` can be interpreted as

> There exists a number `K > 0` independent from `d`, `m`, or `delta`, such that for any value of `d`, `m` and `delta`
>
> ```
> a < b + K * f(d,m,delta)
> ```

For those who are familiar with the quantifier notation used in mathematical logic and elsewhere this is exactly

```
 (Exists) K > 0 (For all) d, m, delta ( a < b + K * f(d,m,delta) )
```

Here `a` stays for `e(h^)`, `b` stays for `e(h*)`, and `f(d,m,delta)` for 
`sqrt[d/m log(m/d) + 1/m log(1/delta)]`